# How to add a possble value to a MySQL SET type in php, without know the current values

Tags: php, mysql, set, addition

Hi everybody and sorry for my english.

I have the column "*example*" that is a **SET** type.
I have to make a php page where you can add values to that column.

First of all I need to know what is just in "*example*", to prevent the adding of an existing value by a control. Second of all I need to add the new value.

Here's what I had thinked  to do.

```
//I just made the connection to the db in PDO or MySQLi
$newValue=$_POST['value']; //I take the value to add in the possible values from a form
//Now I have to "extract" all the possible values. Can't think how.

//I think I can store the values into an array
$result=$sql->fetch();  //$sql is the query to extract all the possible values from "example"

//So now i can do a control with a foreach
foreach($result as $control){
     if ($newValue == $control){
          //error message, break the foreach loop
     }
}
//Now, if the code arrives here there isn't erros, so the "$newValue" is different from any other values stored in "example", so I need to add it as a possible value
$sql=$conn->query("ALTER TABLE 'TableName' CHANGE 'example' 'example' SET('$result', '$newValue')"); //<- where $result is the all existing possible values of "example"
```

In PDO or MySQLi, it's indifferent

Thanks for the help

Comment: Your first step would be to connect to the database from PHP. Are you using MySQLi or PDO to do that? I assume you're not using regular MySQL, considering it's either deprecated or removed, depending on your PHP version. Have you tried anything so far in that regard? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing your code and a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also help to clearly state exactly what you're trying to achieve, as it's a little unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the column definition with a query from `information_schema.columns`

Assuming the table is in the current database (and assuming we are cognizant of `lower_case_table_names` setting in choosing to use mixed case for table names)

```
 SELECT c.column_type 
   FROM information_schema.columns c
  WHERE c.table_schema = DATABASE()
  WHERE c.table_name   = 'TableName'
    AND c.column_name  = 'example'
```

Beware of the limit on the number of elements allowed in a SET definition.

Remove the closing paren from the end, and append `',newval')`.

---

Personally, I don't much care for the idea of running an `ALTER TABLE` as part of the application code. Doing that is going to do an implicit commit in a transaction, and also require an exclusive table / metadata lock while the operation is performed.

Comment: Only few questions... a)With the information.schema, I get the possible values of a SET or all the configuration of that column?  b)Can I put the result in an array?   c)After the control, how can I put the newValue into the column? Is correct, at least the concept, of my idea with an ALTER TABLE ?

Comment: a) the query in this question returns a string (VARCHAR) the column_type of the column as it would appear in a CREATE TABLE statement. For a column with SET datatype, you would get back something like `SET('apple','banana','cherry')`. (Other columns in information_schema.columns contain other attributes.)  b) once we return a string from the database, we can do whatever we want with it.  c) yes, the ALTER TABLE statement would be how we would change the column definition. N.B. in the SET definition, do not change the *order* of the values... stored rows reference position(s) in the SET list

Comment: Ok so, If the return value is a varchar which is: `SET('apple','banana','cherry')`

I can use a string control to delete the last char (the "(" ) and then, use the query `"ALTER TABLE 'TableName' CHANGE 'example' 'example'".$return.", '$newValue') ");`

Right?

Comment: The ALTER TABLE should include the full column definition, including the attributes for nullability, default value, column comment, et al.  Before I included *any* string into the text of a SQL statement, I would make sure sure that it was *safe* for inclusion... white list values that will be accepted, validate them with some checks, and properly escaping values ... (consider a `$newValue` that includes a single quote, or some combination of single quotes and commas, parens, e.g. "**`abc'der''p`**"  or e.g. "**`ab'',''c'') OR 'derp`**"

Comment: So, due to the complexity of the thing I adopted a different way to solve my problem. Thanks for the help and don't doubt, I will study and learn this thing of the SET to use it in a possible future.

Comment: @MattiaFrusca:  We typically reserve `SET` datatype for special cases of strictly predetermined values. And we don't modify the definition of the column when a user request can have any new value that they want to store. Running an ALTER TABLE can  kill concurrency; and we typically don't grant ALTER TABLE priv to the application (its more problems than it solves.) Also, storing comma separated lists is an anti-pattern, see Chapter 2 in Bill Karwin's book https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557(available from amazon and other fine booksellers.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a **SET** type - you should know what values you add. Otherwise, simply use **VARCHAR** type.

Comment: I need a SET type, I know the values that I add but not the values that are stored. I made an exaample:

"example" : {'Hello', 'World'};

The user "Gianni" add "Fine" to the set so:

"example" : {'Hello', 'World', 'Fine'};

Now another user want to add another value.

I don't know exatly which values are in the SET and I cannot control and update the php page each time